# Letters get strange spacing in my SVG on some computers

Tags: images

*(I hope that this is the correct community, I normally just use programmers.se and stackoverflow)*

I got a SVG from a designer.

The problem is that it looks weird on some computers and I have no idea why.

Here is a sample:

[image]

Full image: 
https://coderr.io/img/howitworks.svg

Comment: What web application are you using to open the SVG?

Comment: tried with IE, Chrome and Firefox. I think I've found the problem. the SVG contains positioning of characters instead of using text boxes. Is a problem when the specified font is not found.